# How to save multiple text object from HTML inside list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 8 objects of dataString. "dataString" is an object that I call from attachment1, which is a list that I forward from a controller.

This is my code in HTML:

```
<% int nilai = 0; %>
<c:forEach items="${attachment1}" var="a">
     <div class="w3-image w3-padding">
          <div id="ini">${a.dataString}</div>
          <%=nilai = nilai + 1%>
</c:forEach>
```

this is my code in javascript:

```
var blob = [];

blob.push(document.getElementById('ini').innerHTML);

var blobLength = blob.length;
console.log(blob);
console.log(blobLength);
```

But, when I run and show on the webpage, I saw this result in inspect element:

[result on the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vt4V.png)
as you can see on the picture, the result from java can show perfectly on a webpage.

[result when inspecting element in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uri5f.png)
but in the console, you can see, from 8 string, there is only 1 string that input on the list in javascript.

How to repair it? so that I can put all dataString inside the list on the javascript?

Comment: Use classes instead of ids. ID should be unique per page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the duplicate `id`'s by common class (`ini` in my example) since the identifier should be unique in the same document :

```
<% int nilai = 0; %>
<c:forEach items="${attachment1}" var="a">
     <div class="w3-image w3-padding">
          <div class="ini">${a.dataString}</div>
          <%=nilai = nilai + 1%>
</c:forEach>
```

Then in your JS get all the elements with the class `ini` and loop through them using `foreach` fetching the content using `.textContent` attribute and pushing it to the `blob` array :

```
var blob = [];

document.getElementsByClassName('ini').forEach( function(item) { ;
    blob.push(item.textContent);
}

var blobLength = blob.length;

console.log(blob);
console.log(blobLength);
```

**NOTE :** You should close the `w3-image` div using `</div>` in your `c:forEach` loop

Comment: You're welcome, Welcome to StackOverflow and Congratulation, you've earned the **[VoteUp privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)** consider to use it ;)